# Azure execute yarn on kudu service (webapp) - 'yarn' is not recognized

Tags: azure, yarnpkg, kudu

On an azure deployment, I am using the following to execute yarn install directly on the webapp server:

```
npm install -g yarn   && yarn install --skip-integrity-check
```

The problem is that this works and SOMETIMES doesn't. It seems that sometimes yarn is not found. I couldn't figure out, why sometimes it works and then it just stops working.

Do I have to use the full path for yarn? `D:\local\AppData\npm\yarn`

```
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7439282Z D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm install -g yarn   && yarn install --skip-integrity-check 
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7439644Z 
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7440137Z > yarn@1.22.10 preinstall D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7440995Z > :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7441325Z 
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7441829Z D:\local\AppData\npm\yarn -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7442646Z D:\local\AppData\npm\yarnpkg -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7443189Z + yarn@1.22.10
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7443594Z added 1 package in 0.875s
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7443855Z 
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7444299Z Standard error from script: 
2021-03-10T19:31:01.7483742Z ##[error]'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

2021-03-10T19:31:02.7144847Z ##[error]Error: Unable to run the script on Kudu Service. Error: Error: Executed script returned '1' as return code. Error: 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

```
2021-03-11T06:55:18.2613504Z Executing given script on Kudu service.
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4701733Z Standard output from script: 
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4702407Z 
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4703114Z D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm install -g yarn   && D:\local\AppData\npm\yarn install --skip-integrity-check 
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4704324Z 
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4704999Z > yarn@1.22.10 preinstall D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4742533Z > :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4743040Z 
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4743665Z D:\local\AppData\npm\yarn -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4744393Z D:\local\AppData\npm\yarnpkg -> D:\local\AppData\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4745016Z + yarn@1.22.10
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4746794Z updated 1 package in 0.704s
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4747310Z yarn install v1.22.10
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4747835Z [1/4] Resolving packages...
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4748544Z [2/4] Fetching packages...
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4749983Z info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4750800Z info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4751807Z info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4752623Z info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4753199Z [3/4] Linking dependencies...
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4753658Z [4/4] Building fresh packages...
2021-03-11T06:56:20.4754093Z Done in 55.19s.
```